# How a torrent user gets a chunk of data from other user?

Tags: networking, torrent

In torrent, one/multiple guy seeds and one/multiple guy downloads in pree to pree fashion, but it works well though user don't have public IP on their computer. 
How they are establishing and transmitting data without having public IP?

Answer (score -1):

See this. Here everything is fully explained
https://www.quora.com/How-do-torrents-work-5